# DataSketches Theta Sketch not working properly

Tags: druid

I am having problems with getting correct distinct count numbers from Theta Sketch DataSketches module.

The ingestion spec I am using looks sth like this

```
    "granularitySpec" : 
    {
        "type" : "uniform",
        "segmentGranularity" : "HOUR",
        "queryGranularity" : "HOUR",
        "intervals": ["${hourToProcess.intervalFormat}"]
    }

    ..........

    "dimensionsSpec" :
    {
       "dimensions" : [
            "dimension1",
            "dimension2",
            ......
            "dimensionN"
        ]
    }

    ..........

    "timestampSpec" :
     {
         "format" : "${hourToProcess.ingestionDateFormat}",
         "column" : "eventTimestamp"
     }

    ..........

    "metricsSpecs" :
     [
         .........,
         {"type": "thetaSketch", "name": "uniqueUsers", "fieldName": "uniqueUsers"}
         ........
     ]
```

The field `uniqueUsers` is a String.

If I query Druid in the following way without any filtering or grouping operation

```
    {
      "type" : "thetaSketch",
      "fieldName" : "uniqueUsers",
      "isInputThetaSketch": true
     }
```

the results are correct. But If I do any sort of filtering or grouping by dimensions

```
    "filter": {
      "type": "selector",
      "dimension": "dimensionX",
      "value": "1"
    }
```

the results are much higher than the expected values.

Is there anything wrong internally with Theta Sketch or with my configuration?

I also want to add that if I use DataSketches HLL instead of ThetaSketch I get much better results.

Answer (score 0):

Since the ThetaSketch supports set-based operations (union, intersect, difference), you'll need to specify the filter, aggregations, and postAggregations sections in your query. These sections are critical to compute the correct results. In my opinion, the filter section is the most critical since it defines the dimension and values that will be merged in the postAggregations section.

The following Druid doc is very helpful. However, their example is a groupBy query. I believe their example assumes the data is in raw form and a ThetaSketch needs to be computed at query time. In your case, your sketch is already pre-computed at ingest, so, a timeseries query will be much faster.

https://druid.apache.org/docs/latest/development/extensions-core/datasketches-theta.html

Hope that helps.